# python regular expression : How can I filter only special characters?

Tags: python, regex

I want to check either given words contain special character or not.
so below is my python code

The literal 'a@bcd' has '@', so it will be matchd and it's ok.
but 'a1bcd' has no special character. but it was filtered too!!

```
import re
regexp = re.compile('[~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+\[\]{}\\|;:\'\",.<>/?]+')

if regexp.search('a@bcd') :
    print 'matched!! nich catch!!'

if regexp.search('a1bcd') :
    print 'something is wrong here!!!'
```

result :
python ../special_char.py 
matched!! nich catch!!
something is wrong here!!!

I have no idea why it works like above..someone help me..T_T;;;
thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the dash in you regular expression to the start of the `[]` group, like this:

```
regexp = re.compile('[-~`!@#$%^&*()_=+\[\]{}\\|;:\'\",.<>/?]+')
```

Where you had the dash, it was read with the surrounding characters as `)-_` and since it is inside `[]` it is interpreted as asking to match a range from `)` to `_`. If you move the dash to just after the `[` it has no special meaning and instead matches itself.

Here's an interactive session showing the specific problem there was in your regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.search('[)-_]', 'abcd')
None
>>> print re.search('[)-_]', 'a1b')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f71082247e8>
>>> print re.search('[)-_]', 'a1b').group(0)
1
```

After fixing it:

```
>>> print re.search('[-)_]', 'a1b')
None
```

Unless there's some reason not visible in your question, I'd also say that the final `+` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

`re` will be relatively slow for this

I'd suggest trying

```
specialchars = '''-~`!@#$%^&*()_=+[]{}\\|;:'",.<>/?'''
len(word) != len(word.translate(None, specialchars))
```

or

```
set(word) & set(specialchars)
```